# Compiling java file to create serveclass ( tomcat learning)

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, backend

I followed the following tutorial:
http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Tomcat_HowTo.html 
to bulid a helloword servlet app. I meet problems when i was applying step6, which is about how to compile the servlet java file using javac.The tutorial said using:
[image: command]

```
javac -cp .:$HOME/myWebProject/tomcat/lib/servlet-api.jar HelloServlet.java
```

the location of my servlet-api. jar is:

```
/home/xianhaoni/apache-tomcat-9.0.14/lib
```

so i simply type:

```
javac -cp .:$HOME/home/xianhaoni/apache-tomcat-9.0.14/lib/servlet-api.j
ar HelloServlet.java
```

it doesn't work, i also tried:

```
javac -cp /home/xianhaoni/apache-tomcat-9.0.14/lib/servlet-api.j
ar HelloServlet.java
```

Neither of these two works.

However when i directly move the servlet.jar file to the directory [image: directory] of the HelloServlet.java file, and simply using

```
javac -cp servlet-api.jar HelloServlet.java
```

it compiles successfully, which means the format of the path of the jar file is wrong. Can someone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: IMO try the command `cd /home/xianhaoni/apache-tomcat-9.0.14/lib` and if you can see the `servlet-api.jar` that means your path to servelt api jar is correct.

Comment: it says " No such file or directory" , it should be a reallly simpe problem,  but i just couldn't find out why

Comment: It means path is incorrect.Just go to the directory where `apache-tomcat-9.0.14` is installed and go inside `lib` and then just get the path. Now compare it to the one you are using. You may find the error.

Comment: Thank you very much, I found the problem, when i type cd /home/  or cd /home/xianhaoni/, it works well, however when i type  cd /home/xianhaoni/apache-tomcat-9.0.14/, it says "no such directory", i renamed the apache-tomacte-9.0.14, now it works well, i might have name this folder with some wierd character that i didn't notice. now everyting works well. Thank you very much.